# Dynamics AX Bypass Checklists

Tags: microsoft-dynamics-crm

If you have installation checklist items wanting attention (full compile, synchronize, etc.) sometimes AX 2012 will boot to basically a blank gray screen with no options or navigation on it.

I ran into this once before, and there is either a command-line switch or hotkey you can press to ignore waiting checklists and go ahead and boot to the user interface.  Unfortunately, I must not have written it down.

Anyone remember the secret?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CTRL-W will open a new workspace without the checklists.